Macbook pro 2015 13'' running monterey keeps on restarting even when I start up in safe mode
Macbook pro 2015 13'' running on monterey keeps on restarting upon login. This is the case even when I start it up on safe mode.
Also when I start up and do not login the computer restarts after some time.

Can you boot into Recovery?  Try installing macOS onto an external drive and booting from that to test.  if it's stable, you might have a corrupt installation

I found a few steps that might resolve the issue or at least find the culprit:
Run Apple Diagnostics: Restart your Mac and hold the 'D' key to check for hardware issues.
Reset SMC: Shut down your Mac, hold Shift + Control + Option and the power button for 10 seconds, then turn it back on.
Reset NVRAM/PRAM: Restart, then immediately hold Option + Command + P + R for about 20 seconds.
If these steps don't resolve the issue, it could very likely be due to a more serious hardware problem, especially considering the age of your MacBook Pro.
